# libsodium: crypto_stream_xor vs crypto_secretbox

Tags: php, encryption, libsodium

If I'm reading the documentation for [crypto_stream_xor](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/advanced/stream_ciphers/xsalsa20) and [crypto_secretbox](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption) correctly, both functions use XSalsa20. The former does not have any authentication whereas the latter does. Pursuant to this I would expect the first few bytes of `crypto_secretbox` to be the same as the first few bytes of `crypto_stream_xor` but alas they are not. eg.

```
<?php

$a = sodium_crypto_secretbox('zzz', str_repeat('z', 24), str_repeat('z', 32));
echo bin2hex($a) . "\n";
$a = sodium_crypto_stream_xor('zzz', str_repeat('z', 24), str_repeat('z', 32));
echo bin2hex($a);
```

The output is as follows:

```
f575a1681d3ee38b0667690c2141f8af6c894d
4c832d
```

See online: https://3v4l.org/rqhvJ

`crypto_secretbox` is (I assume) appending an additional 16 bytes (128 bits), which is the length of the Poly1305 tag. But if they're both using XSalsa20 I would expect the first three bytes to at least by the same but they're not.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication tag that `crypto_secretbox()` includes is stored in the first 16 bytes.

Also, with `crypto_secretbox()`, as pointed out by Squeamish Ossifrage, the first 32 bytes of the stream cipher are not added to the ciphertext. They are used as the poly1305 key.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$a = sodium_crypto_secretbox('zzz', str_repeat('z', 24), str_repeat('z', 32));
echo bin2hex($a) . "\n";
$a = sodium_crypto_stream_xor('00000000000000000000000000000000zzz', str_repeat('z', 24), str_repeat('z', 32));
echo bin2hex($a) . "\n";
```

instead.

crypto_secretbox uses the first 32 bytes of the pad generated by XSalsa20 as the Poly1305 authenticator key.  The details are given in the [NaCl validation document](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/valid.html).  This is also why the NaCl C API has apparently weird zero-padding business that everyone hates: the caller is expected to provide temporary storage in the ciphertext buffer for the 32-byte Poly1305 authenticator key.